# Javascript some() method and additional parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to check if at least one element in an array pass a condition.
The condition depends on a variable.

For example, I'm using something like this:

```js
function condition(previousValue, index, array) {
    return additonalValue.indexOf(previousValue) + previousValue.indexOf(additonalValue) < -1;
}
```

I can't figure out how can I pass the "additonalValue" parameter to the `array.some(condition)` expression.

I'm using jQuery so, an alternative for it is welcome.

**Is there a way to pass a parameter to array.some() method?**

Comment: Why not pass it through a closure ?

Comment: If you're trying to check if **all** values in the array match, shouldn't you be using `every()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, I need to check if any element pass a condition. I will modify the question. Thanks :). @dystroy, how would you propose it to do it?

Comment: Then what do you want to be returned once it passes it?

Comment: What you're doing is just about equal to `additonalValue == previousValue` as checking if one value contains the other, then if the other contains the one, they would have to be the same ?

Comment: @CruzDiablo Made it an answer so I can write the code.

Comment: Maybe the example is not the best, but let's suppose that it is `previousValue == additionalParameter`.

Comment: @dcodesmith It should return true if any of the array elements pass the condition.

Comment: The fact you name the first argument `previousValue` is a little disturbing due to the behavior of `some`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass an additional parameter to the function that is placed inside the `some` method you can use `bind`.

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var otherValue = 'e';
function someFunction(externalParameter, element, index, array) {
    console.log(externalParameter, element, index, array);
    return (element == externalParameter);
}
myArray.some(someFunction.bind(null, otherValue));
```

This would give you:

```
e a 0 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
e b 1 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
e c 2 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
e d 3 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
false
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a closure looks like the simplest solution :

```
var additonalValue = 79;
var r = myArray.some(function(previousValue) {
    return additonalValue.indexOf(previousValue) + previousValue.indexOf(additonalValue) < -1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `some()` function accepts additional arguments in the form of an array, that is set to `this` inside the callback, so you could pass a number of values that way :

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var val = 'two';

var r = arr.some(function(value) {
    return this[0] == value;
}, [val]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r79wp/)